# Why am I not getting the Blank Points on Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep

I finished all 3 files on proud mode, finished the final episode, and collected all Xehanort reports and the stickers (I got 140 points). Did I forget to do something?

Comment: You finished all three games on proud mode, but did you also the get 140 sticker points and Xehanort reports all three games as well?